# How to perform query-replace excluding LaTeX math?

Tags: latex, query-replace, isearch-filter-predicate

I have this test code:

```latex
foo

\begin{equation}
  foo
\end{equation}

foo

$foo$

foo
```

I want to replace "foo" with "bar" everywhere but LaTeX math, so I have written these functions:

```el
(defun test-a ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((isearch-filter-predicate 'skip-equation-env))

    (query-replace-regexp "foo"
                          "bar" nil (point-min) (point-max))))

(defun skip-equation-env (beg end)
  (catch 'skip-region
    (save-excursion
      (save-match-data
        (when (and (looking-back "\\\\begin{equation}\\([[:graph:] \n]+\\)")
                   (looking-at "\\([[:graph:] \n]+\\)\\\\end{equation}"))
          (throw 'skip-region nil)))
      t)))

(defun test-b ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((isearch-filter-predicate 'skip-inline-math))

    (query-replace-regexp "foo"
                          "bar" nil (point-min) (point-max))))

(defun skip-inline-math (beg end)
  (catch 'skip-region
    (save-excursion
      (save-match-data
        (when (face-at-point beg 'tex-math)
          (throw 'skip-region nil)))
      t)))
```

I have adapted `skip-equation-env` and `skip-inline-math` from another code to be fit to my case, so I'm not sure of all their lines.

I have tested these functions successfully, but I would like to know if there is a more suitable way to write them using `isearch-filter-predicate`. I am new to `isearch`.

I am not allowed to use `auctex`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need to discriminate between in-line mathematics and mathematical environments, you can simply use `texmathp`. You don't need to install AUCTeX, but you can retrieve the texmathp.el file from GitHub: https://github.com/emacsmirror/auctex/blob/master/texmathp.el.

```el
(require 'texmathp)

(defun omit-maths (beg end)
  "Return nil if some text BEG to END is in a LaTeX maths environment or in in-line
maths."
  (catch 'skip-region
    (let ((pos beg))
      (save-excursion
        (save-match-data
          (goto-char pos)
          (while (< pos end)
            (when (texmathp) (throw 'skip-region nil))
            (goto-char (setq pos (1+ pos)))))
        t))))

(defun hold-maths (beg end)
  "Return t if some text BEG to END is NOT in a LaTeX maths environment or in
in-line maths."
  (catch 'skip-region
    (let ((pos beg))
      (save-excursion
        (save-match-data
          (goto-char pos)
          (while (< pos end)
            (unless (texmathp) (throw 'skip-region nil))
            (goto-char (setq pos (1+ pos)))))
        t))))
```

You can also install `AUCTeX` without automatic activation for LaTeX (.tex) files: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/80263/15606