# How to install AUCTeX on Emacs without automatic activation for LaTeX (.tex) files?

Tags: latex, auctex

I am interested in installing AUCTeX on Emacs to support writing LaTeX documents. However, I would prefer to avoid the automatic activation of AUCTeX when opening LaTeX documents and only activate it manually when needed.

Is there a way to install AUCTeX on Emacs without automatically activating it when I open LaTeX documents? What variables or settings should I consider to achieve this behavior?

I mean that I would like the `.tex` files to be opened with the default `latex-mode` and not with `AUCTex`.

I tried:

```el
(setq package-load-list
      '((auctex nil)
        all))

(package-initialize)
```

With these lines, when running the `package-list-packages` command, the `AUCTeX` package appears disabled, but the `.tex` files are opened with the syntax highlighting and functions provided by `AUCTeX`.

I tried also to look at the variable `auto-mode-alist` but in both cases, `auctex` installed or NOT, I found:

```el
 ("\\.tex\\'" . latex-mode)
```

I suspect that `auctex` overwrites the default `latex-mode`.

**Edit.**
When I run `M-x decribe-mode` I get:

> Minor modes enabled in this buffer: Auto-Save Font-Lock
>
> The major mode is LaTeX/P mode defined in tex-mode.el:
>
> This function has :override advice: ‘TeX-latex-mode’.
>
> This is an :override advice, which means that ‘latex-mode’ isn’t run
> at all, and the documentation below may be irrelevant.

But if I run `M-x decribe-variable <RET> major-mode <RET>` I get:

> major-mode is a variable defined in ‘C source code’.
>
> Its value is ‘latex-mode’
> not `LaTeX/P mode`.

This is a little strange to me.

Comment: Do `C-h f latex-mode` to verify your suspicion.

Comment: @NickD I updated my question. I think my suspicion was well-founded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex.html#Loading-the-package):

> ###### 1.2.4 Loading the package
>
> [...]
> Once activated, the modes provided by AUCTeX are used per default for
> all supported file types. If you want to change the modes for which it
> is operative instead of the default, use
>
> `M-x customize-option <RET> TeX-modes <RET>`

Note that you have to use `customize` to set this option; don't `setq` it in your init file (or use `setopt` if you have a recent Emacs).

Answer (score 1):

I followed the [Arash Esbati](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/12242/arash-esbati) answer and I noticed that the variable `Tex-modes`:

```el
(custom-set-variables
 ;; custom-set-variables was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 '(TeX-modes nil)
...
```

is now set in my `.emacs`.

I tried to uninstall and reinstall `auctex` leaving this string in my `.emacs` and it works. Once set, the variable inhibits `AUCTeX` modes to be activated by default.

To activate the `AUCTeX` features you may run, e.g., `M-x TeX-latex-mode`. If you want to restore the default `latex-mode` just type `M-x latex-mode`.