# Installing and Managing texmathp.el Independently from AUCTeX in Emacs

Tags: auctex, texmathp

I'm interested in using `texmathp.el`, a file provided by the AUCTeX package, without having to install the entire AUCTeX package. Is there a way to install `texmathp.el` through Emacs' package manager and keep track of updates to the file separately?

Until now, I have always manually downloaded this file (from here: https://github.com/emacsmirror/auctex/blob/master/texmathp.el).

The current alternative I'm considering is installing AUCTeX but preventing it from being automatically activated when visiting `.tex` files ([How to install AUCTeX on Emacs without automatic activation for LaTeX (.tex) files?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/80250/15606)). However, I'm curious if there's a method to solely install and manage `texmathp.el`.

I appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to achieve this.

Comment: Not unless somebody (maybe you) creates a package with that file only (always AFAIK).

Comment: @NickD Perhaps I could ask the maintainers of the AUCTeX package to do it, as they are the ones responsible for that file.

Comment: You can of course, but it would be a maintenance burden for them, so I wouldn't be surprised if they declined.